# Not contain certain word in jQuery Validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I tried to validate a text field data that NOT include the word ABC in for example.  This is my code:

```
function ValInput()
{
     $.validator.addMethod("notEqualTo",function (value, element, param) { 
        return this.optional(element) || value != param ;
     }, "Name must not contain ABC");

      $("#Form1").validate({
        rules: {
            <%=txtName.UniqueID%>: {
                required: true,
                notEqualTo: "ABC"
            }

        },   //rules
         messages: {
             <%=txtName.UniqueID%>: {
                 required: "Name is a required field.",
                 notEqual: "Name must not contain the word ABC"
            }
         },           
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            alert(error.text());
        }
    }); 
}
```

The field validate if the name is ABC; however I want to validate if the ABC is in the middle or at the end or any place in the Name, how do I do that? How do I use the indexOf (in jquery) for this situation ?  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `indexOf` method like this.

```
var word = "Name must not contain the word ABC";
if(word.indexOf("ABC")>=0)
   //do something
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/627rnkob/)

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex:

```
var pattern = /^((?!ABC).)*$/;
console.log(!pattern.test('testAbc')) //false;
console.log(!pattern.test('testABC')) //true;
```